# HTML to Image – Canvas without preview

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to create images from HTML. I found that website where they show how it can be done: [codepedia.info](https://codepedia.info/convert-html-to-image-in-jquery-div-or-table-to-jpg-png/)

Yes, it works. But you have to press a “*preview button*” and afterward a “*download link*” to save the graphic. I want users to press only one button and download the graphic directly without the preview.
Also other users asked for that and the webmaster explained that it's easily possible as follows:

> All you need to copy both button code into one function and comment
>   this line `$("#previewImage").append(canvas);`.

There are 2 parts of javascript. Unfortunately I'm to clueless in javascript to know what to do and don't get it to run. Can somebody help please?

```
var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable

$("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
     html2canvas(element, {
     onrendered: function (canvas) {
            $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
            getCanvas = canvas;
         }
     });
});


$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
     var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
     // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
     var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
     $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Adding another answer for dynamic html content)

I'm using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to see changes in the `#content` div to call `html2canvas` and update the `#download-link` anchor's `href`

Here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mvy361h6/12/ You can type things in the div to change it's content

Comment: That's awesome and so much better than the idea I had in the beginning. Anyway, your JSFiddle works fine, but when I copy the 3 parts (HTML, CSS, SCRIPT) the download-link is neither clickable nor underlined. In your JSFiddle it is. I do not understand what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: Does that also work if the div an image should be created from has a background image?

Comment: @Gerd Poy The bug that jsfiddle wraps the js in an `onLoad` which you haven't done. Check this one : https://jsfiddle.net/mvy361h6/15/ it'll work

Comment: I don't know... I don't want to bother you, but for my understanding this https://jsfiddle.net/gerd7107/sbhvt0kL/ is an exact copy of your JSFiddle. Yours has a download link, mine not.

Comment: @Gerd Poy Open this https://jsfiddle.net/mvy361h6/15/ and check the resources at the left... Your fiddle does not have the html2canvas.min.js resource file... And I appreciate the fact that you don't want to bother me... But it's fine.. Np at all :)

Comment: Oh my good, I have it. I didn't recognize the resource on the left. JSFiddle is completely new to me. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Gerd Poy Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Well.. It's pretty simple you have to just unwrap the html2canvas code from the click listener and remove the preview button...

So this...

```
$("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
  html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
      $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
      getCanvas = canvas;
    }
  });
});
```

... becomes this ...

```
html2canvas(element, {
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
    $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
    getCanvas = canvas;
  }
});
```

I am assuming that the html that is to be converted to canvas is static...

And to remove the preview just add `style="display:none"` to the preview element

Here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qm68d7hq/3/

Comment: @Gerd Poy Happy to help :)

Comment: @Gred Poy I would love if you mark my answer as accepted as well... As it worked for you...

Comment: @Gerd Poy Umm... I think the asker can accept an answer without any conditions... Try if you can... No problem if you can't :)

Comment: One further question if I'm allowed:
In the great solution from Devansh J the canvas gets created directly when the page loads. What if the <div> I want to create an image from changes dynamically? In that case I get an image like it was on page load.
Is it possible to change the javascript that way, that the canvas gets just created in the moment the user clicks the download button?

Comment: @Gerd Poy I completely get your question... But that's not possible... But here's a workaround : Everytime the div changes, call html2canvas to update the canvas... In that way the canvas is always up-to-date. If you can tell me how does the div changes (by user interaction? image load? etc) I would be able to help more efficiently

Comment: Thank you Devansh J. The div will change by user interaction. Users should be able 2 change 2 texts and 2 colors. I tried to make this visible also on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerd7107/4ku15wkx/35/